# How can I setup and verify GRE tunnel pn ubuntu server?

Tags: gre

In the scenario below, I'm going to configure SQUID and WCCP for web caching mechanism.

Currently, WCCP is configured on router and squid is configured on UbuntuServer,

but really I do not know anything about GRE tunnel and how it can be configured on Ubuntu Server.

Can anyone help me, please??

[image]

Comment: why do you think you may need such a tunnel while all is in the same place?

Comment: just because it is a requirement in WCCP configuration. all documents are saying, it's necessary tp have a GRE tunnel between squid server and router.

Comment: for what ever reason you like to do this... maybe this tutorial might give you a good idea of how it works https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/web_filter_https_squid_cisco_wccp/gre_ubuntu.html